# Complete geodesics on a hyperbolic pair of pants

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

I am trying to understand the article by Maryam Mirzakhani about [Simple geodesics and Weil-Petersson volumes](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Emlyubich/Archive/Geometry/Teichmuller%20Space/Mirz3.pdf). In the **third** section of this article, the following proposition is stated. And I want to know why this proposition is correct. I mention the proposition:

**Proposition**: Let $P$ be a hyperbolic pair of pants with (non-empty)geodesic boundary components $\beta_1 , \beta_2, \beta_3$ of lenghts $x_1, x_2, x_3$ respectively. Then $P$ contains $5$ complete geodesics disjoint from $\beta_2 , \beta_3$ and orthogonal to $\beta_1$. More precisley, two of these geodesics meet $\beta_1$ respectively at
$y_1,y_2$ and spiral to $\beta_3$, the other two meet $\beta_1$ respectively at $z_1,z_2$ and spiral to $\beta_2$. there is also a unique common geodesic perpendicular from $\beta_1$ to itself meeting $\beta_1$ perpendicularly at two points $w_1, w_2$.

[image]

Comment: I don't have time right now to draw pictures, but: To see the unique geodesic from $\beta_1$ to itself, think of the pair of pants as a pair of right-angled hexagon, the saddle geodesic will be apparent. To see the spiraling geodesics, develop the pair of pants into $\mathbb{H}^2$, then you will be able to find a geodesic perpendicular to the developing image of $\beta_1$ and asymptotically approaches the developing image of $\beta_3$. This is in 3.9 of Thurston's notes.

Comment: Actually, none of these is a complete geodesic, rather, it is a geodesic ray